# Parameterization Of Intersection Between Sphere And Cylinder

Tags: calculus

Find the parameterization of the curve of the intersection between

$x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ and $x^2+y^2=Rx$ where $z>0$

I started with trying to get to a known formula, like an ellipse, circle. etc.

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$$

$$x^2+y^2=Rx$$

So

$$Rx+z^2=R^2$$

Which did not lead me to any formula I know.

I went to use the parameterization of a sphere:

$$x=\rho \sin \phi \cos \theta$$

$$y=\rho \sin \phi \sin \theta$$

$$ z = \rho \cos \phi$$

Due to $z>0$ we get that $\phi\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

In the cylinder only $\theta, \rho$ are parameters then:

$$x^2+y^2=Rx$$

$$x=\rho \cos \theta$$

$$y = \rho \sin \theta$$

So:

$$\rho^2=R\rho \cos \theta\Rightarrow \rho = R \cos \theta$$

So:

$$x=R \sin \phi \cos^2 \theta$$

$$y=R \sin \phi \sin \theta \cos \theta$$

$$ z = R \cos \phi \cos \theta$$

But this is a parameterization with two variables there I need to get a parameterization with one variable

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Do not involve $\rho$ but only $R$

A space curve is to be parameterized only on a single independent variable.

Find $\phi $ as a function of $\theta$ using

$$x^2+y^2 =R x$$

[Viviani's curve](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VivianisCurve.html)

Comment: I mange to understand that it is $(x-\frac{R}{2})^2+y^2=(\frac{R}{2})^2$

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple in cartesian co-ordinates. Going ahead of $Rx+z^2=R^2$
$$x=\frac{R^2-z^2}{R}$$ Putting it back in the cylinder equation gives
$$y^2=R^2-z^2-{\frac{(R^2-z^2)^2}{R^2}}$$